# when casting from a number the value must be a number less than infinity 2

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

in my code i have a request to  oracle table called retenue, the query in toad is fine but in .net does not fire the exception in the title.
fire the exception in this line :

> (int)session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).UniqueResult()

:
please any help.

```
var sql = "select id_retenue from RETENUE where ID_BAR = " + idbar + " and ID_ORGANISATION = " + idorg;
int ret_id = (int)session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).UniqueResult();
```

Comment: First of all : use bind variables. For performance and more important to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Probably returned value is to big to be converted to int. Please split int casting and query execution to separate lines to be sure.

Comment: problem resolved    :          int ret_id = real_value == null ? 0 : Int32.Parse(real_value.ToString());